# How can i calculate sum of all numbers in text with python?

Tags: python

input
essum magis 45 kohlrabi azuki bean garlic. Dandelion cucumber -1 earthnut pea peanut water 10.5 spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green

output
54.5

explanation
45 + 10.5 -1 = 54.5

I'm not allowed to import packages yet! im really lost i have been working on this for the 4 hours

```
n = input('Enter an Alpha-Numeric String: ')
n_sum = 0
temp_num = ''
for i in n:
    if i.isalpha():
        if temp_num != '':
            n_sum = n_sum + int(temp_num)
            temp_num = 0
else:
    temp_num = str(temp_num) + str(i)

if temp_num != '':
    n_sum = n_sum + int(temp_num)
    temp_num = 0

print(n_sum)
```

Comment: thank you so much, may i ask you if it's possible to edit my code

Answer (score 2):

Split the sentence on space. Check if each word is a number. If it is, convert to a number and add to total:

```
n = input('Enter an Alpha-Numeric String: ')
n_sum = 0
for word in n.split():
    try:
        n_sum += float(word)
    except ValueError:
        # float() will throw an exception if not a number
        pass
print(n_sum)
```

Comment: Omg, u really saved me, thank you so much, i wasn't able to think more about it i spend my day on it